Don't know how to Bind with MVVM
I've been following tutorial on how to make first app with MVVM and I can't wrap my head around binding ViewModel to the MainWindow and then get the data from in on the screen.I get 2 rows of empty text boxes (I have 10 objects in my .json file)
Here's what I've done:
namespace MVVC.Model
{
    public class CoffeeModel { }

    public class Coffee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [JsonProperty("coffee_type")]
        private string _type;
        [JsonProperty("price")]
        private double _price;
        [JsonProperty("roast_level")]
        private string _roast;
        [JsonProperty("origin_country")]
        private string _origin;

        public string type
        {
            get => _type;
            set
            {
                if (value != _type)
                {
                    _type = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("type");
                }
            }
        }

        public double price
        {
            get => _price;
            set
            {
                if (value != _price) 
                {
                    _price = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("price");
                }
            }

        }

        public string roast
        {
            get => _roast;
            set
            {
                if(value != _roast)
                {
                    _roast = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("roast");
                }
            }

        }

        public string origin
        {
            get =>_origin;
            set
            {
                if (_origin != value)
                {
                    _origin = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("origin");
                }
            }
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }



namespace MVVC.ViewModel
{
    public class CoffeeViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CoffeeModel> CoffeeList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CoffeeModel>();

      
        public void LoadCoffee()
        {

            CoffeeList=new ObservableCollection<CoffeeModel>();
            string json = File.ReadAllText("CoffeeData.json");
            var CoffeeModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CoffeeModel>>(json);
            foreach(var coffee in CoffeeModels)
            {
                CoffeeList.Add(coffee);
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace MVVC.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CoffeeView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CoffeeView : UserControl
    {
        public CoffeeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        
        }
    }
}


I don't know if I should select DataContext here^ I can't see the XAML of this file because it says that it ended unexpectedly if I bind here
<UserControl x:Class="MVVC.Views.CoffeeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVC.Views" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment = "Left">

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = CoffeeList}" >

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Text = "{Binding Path = type, Mode = TwoWay}" 
                        Width = "100" Margin = "3 5 3 5"/>

                            <TextBox Text = "{Binding Path = price, Mode = TwoWay}" 
                        Width = "100" Margin = "0 5 3 5"/>

                            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Path = roast, Mode = OneWay}" 
                        Margin = "0 5 3 5"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>


namespace MVVC
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CoffeeViewControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MVVC.ViewModel.CoffeeViewModel coffeeViewModelObject= new ViewModel.CoffeeViewModel();
            coffeeViewModelObject.LoadCoffee();

            CoffeeViewControl.DataContext= coffeeViewModelObject;
        }


    }
}


Implement your Coffee.cs with INotifyPropertyChanged in order to communicate accordingly with the view like below :
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MVVM.Model
{
    public class Coffee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _type;
        private double _price;
        private string _roast;
        private string _origin;

        [JsonProperty("coffee_type")]
        public string Type
        {
            get => _type;
            set
            {
                if (value != _type)
                {
                    _type = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Type));
                }
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty("price")]
        public double Price
        {
            get => _price;
            set
            {
                if (value != _price)
                {
                    _price = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Price));
                }
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty("roast_level")]
        public string Roast
        {
            get => _roast;
            set
            {
                if (value != _roast)
                {
                    _roast = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Roast));
                }
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty("origin_country")]
        public string Origin
        {
            get => _origin;
            set
            {
                if (value != _origin)
                {
                    _origin = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Origin));
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

Change your CoffeeViewModel.cs to LoadCoffee like below :
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MVVM.Model;


namespace MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class CoffeeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Coffee> _coffeeList;

        public ObservableCollection<Coffee> CoffeeList
        {
            get => _coffeeList;
            set
            {
                if (value != _coffeeList)
                {
                    _coffeeList = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CoffeeList));
                }
            }
        }

        public CoffeeViewModel()
        {
            LoadCoffee();
        }

        public void LoadCoffee()
        {
         string json = @"
          [
            { 'coffee_type': 'Espresso', 'price': 2.5, 'roast_level': 'Dark', 'origin_country': 'Italy' },
            { 'coffee_type': 'Latte', 'price': 3.0, 'roast_level': 'Medium', 'origin_country': 'France' }
          ]";

        var coffeeModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coffee>>(json);
        CoffeeList = new ObservableCollection<Coffee>(coffeeModels);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

And your view would look something like this :
<UserControl x:Class="MVVM.Views.CoffeeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CoffeeList}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Type, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" Margin="3 5 3 5"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Price, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" Margin="0 5 3 5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Roast, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0 5 3 5"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

And finally don't forget to Set the DataContext of MainWindow to CoffeeViewModel like below :
<Window x:Class="MVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:CoffeeView />
    </Grid>
</Window>

Via following the above you will be able to bind the data in json to the viewModel

Now I get an error:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'A member with the name 'price' already exists on 'MVVC.Model.Coffee'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.'
on
LoadCoffee();

Answer update check now

Thank you,I've just figured it out by myself and came to thank you,gonna start by myself from now,thanks again!

Happy to help.. Appreciate a upvote for the answer. Thanks in advance
